# What happens to special cars?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Does anyone know what happens to the special cars you get in the garages (Turismo, etc) if they get destroyed while out in them?

What about if you just park it up and then do other stuff? Do you still lose your mods?

Answer (score 1):

You mean the cars from the garage freebie list?  Obviously, if you've modded it, and it gets destroyed, those mods are lost.  But the car type is always selectable from the list, and thus can be recreated at any time.

Answer (score 0):

If you buy mods for a (let's say Turismo R) and you leave it or blow it up, and get another from the garage, the mods will not rollover, you will have to repurchase